# TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined - Not sure where it's originating as I don't use replace in the repo

Tags: typescript, react-native, mobile, expo, command-line-interface

When I run my expo project I am getting a console warning stating.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
    at matchFileNameOrURLFromStackTrace (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/utils/matchFileNameOrURLFromStackTrace.ts:16:42)
    at logStackTrace (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/exp.ts:548:31)
    at logWithLevel (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/exp.ts:590:11)
    at Object.write (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/exp.ts:656:13)
```

I am unsure where this is coming from as I only use replace is below but I have changed that and still get the error.

```
const makeURL = (url: string) => {
    return `${API_URL}/${url?.replace(/^\/+/, '')}`;
};
```

I have had a look for `matchFileNameOrURLFromStackTrace` and there are no traces of it anywhere.

Any help to be pointed in the right direction would be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Same issue, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Hi @polar, no I still haven't gotten to the bottom of this. I haven't worked on it for a bit, please let me know if you find out why this is :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been fixed (https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/3473).

`npm i -g expo-cli` and that has solved the error for me.